# In what situation would compressed data be larger than input?

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I need to handle compression of data that's largely UTF-8 HTML content in a utility I'm working on. The utility uses zLib and the deflate algorithm to compress data. Is it safe to assume that if the input data size is over 1 kB, compressed data will always be smaller than uncompressed input? (Input data below 1 kB will not be compressed.)

I'm trying to see situations where this assumption would break but apart from near-perfect random input, it seems a safe assumption to me.

**Edit:** the reason I'm wondering about this assumption is because I already have a buffer allocated that's as big as the input data. If my assumption holds, I can reuse this same buffer and avoid another memory allocation.

Comment: Why make the assumption at all?  Just allocate a big enough buffer and be safe.

Comment: @CarlNorum Sure, I can but that doesn't answer my question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can never assume that the compressed data will always be smaller.  In fact, if any sequence is compressed by the algorithm, then you are guaranteed that some other sequence is expanded.

You can use zlib's `deflate()` function to compress as much as it can into your 1K buffer.  Do whatever you need to with that result, then continue with another `deflate()` call writing into that same buffer.

Alternatively you can allocate a buffer big enough for the largest expansion.  The `deflateBound()` or `compressBound()` functions will tell you how much that is.  It's only a small amount more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a good rule of thumb how much more memory is needed to compress all input data in one go? My current buffer is exactly as big as the input data and if I have to over-allocate, I'd like to do it ahead of time. I'd like to avoid calling `deflateBound()` if at all possible - I'm trying to shave off as much time from execution as possible. I assume you have pretty good insight into what counts as a safe buffer. :)

Comment: Just call `deflateBound()`.  It's purpose in life is to be that rule of thumb.  It is extremely simple, so you will not be able to measure its execution time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a sequence of 128 bytes with values 0, 1, 2, ..., 127 will not be compressed by zLib. Technically, it's possible to intentionally create an HTML page that will break your compression scheme, but with normal innocent HTML data you should be almost perfectly safe.

But almost perfectly is not perfectly. If you already have a buffer of that size, I'd advise to attempt the compression with this buffer, and if it turns out that the buffer is not enough (I suppose zLib has means of indicating that), then allocate a larger buffer or simply store an uncompressed version. And make sure you are writing these cases into some log so you could see if it ever fires :)

Comment: Thank you - I guess trying it out is a good idea. The resoning behind the 1 kB lower limit is to allow for sufficient redundancy in the data so that the size assumption holds.